# THREE.js - TypeError: url.search is not a function. (In 'url.search( /\.jpe?g($|\?)/i )', 'url.search' is undefined)

Tags: three.js

I wanted to add a texture to the black sphere, so I added the texture loader and set the image to imx (which is the same grass texture as in the scene).

But it does not load the image.

imx = "/media/accounts/951824539/951824539.jpg"

```
            const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(imx);
            const material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture });

            geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(15, 10, 6);
            var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material2);
            sphere.position.set(-60, 15, -50);
            children.add(sphere);
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the value of the `imx` variable? You're not showing where it's being created, so it's impossible for others to know the cause of the problem. My guess is that it's not a string with the URL, which is [required for `TextureLoader.load()` to work correctly](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/loaders/TextureLoader.load).

If you want to pass an `<img>` element, you can do so with:

`const texture = new THREE.Texture(imx);`

Comment: ah, sure.. this is the output of an alert so I didnt copy them...

Comment: I also tried video with the webcam and that works, in the sphere so, is it maybe because I used imx for the scene already or do I have to get a new image?

Comment: Yeah, you have to make sure you're passing a string to the `.load()` function. No need to name all your variables `imx`, if one of them is a video texture, you can name the other `imageURL` to avoid confusion.